# Python: Activate F6 Key after certain Interval

Tags: python

How to **activate** the **F6 key every x seconds** for the active window,

`x` being whatever number I enter, and the program stops with the hit of like `ctrl+z` or something.

What would be a good way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there a specific reason you want to use Python for this? Also, for what operating system?

Comment: I don't know enough about Python to do repetitive key activations like that. I'm really, really new to it lol. I basically need it for this console emulator I use, theres a minigame in this game I play that takes like 10 solid minutes of timed alternating key hits and is very time consuming, wanting to use this to make automatic game saves (with F6) while I play, so I can restart from a very recent save every time I miss the key timing.
Its sort of cheating I guess lol but I'd like help with this program nonetheless. Its for Windows, btw

Comment: You might want to consider using a "keyboard macro" type program. I know it's less fun than writing your own, but this sort of program can get pretty detailed and might not be suitable as a beginning project. Over at http://superuser.com you should be able to ask about recommendations for such a program.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this might do what you need: http://www.rutherfurd.net/python/sendkeys/

I haven't tried to personally and my initial response was going to be that you're most likely going to need to look into Win32 APIs, but a quick google search turned that up.

Comment: That might be the one I need, just have to stick an infinite loop around it, I think. Should the sent key be interpreted by the system as an actual keypress, if its looping while a different app is active?